# iPhone: Expand UITextView when scrolling

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview, uiimageview, expand

in my iPhone Application I have a `UIImageView` on the top and a `UITextView` below that. I want the `UITextView` to expand to the upper site and cover the `UIImageView` once the User starts scrolling.

A similar effect can be found in the Rdio Application. There you can view the cover on the top and the upcoming title below, once the user starts to scroll, the upcoming titles view expands and covers the cover.

How can that be done?

Thanks.

Comment: Show us what you've done so far to get this to work.

Answer (score 3):

Try to use one of the delegate methods of UIScrollView (UITextView is a subview of UIScrollView).

This should work for you:

```
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
    // From Apple Docs: Tells the delegate when the scroll view is about to start scrolling the content.
```

Implement this method and call your resizing function in it.